# How I can install RRD module in perl?

Tags: 12.04, perl, nagios3

I'm very new to Ubuntu. I'm using Nagios Graph plugin. That plugin needs perl RRD module to be installed on my system.

How I can install that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried RRDtool?

Comment: @Mitch: Ya i have tried that one. But still that plugin say's the package `RRD` is missing under perl module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try installing RRDtool.

`sudo apt-get install rrdtool`

There are lot of RRD perl modules available at [cpan](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=RRD&mode=all). You can install the modules which ever is needed for you using command

`perl -MCPAN -e 'install RRD::Simple'`

Answer (score 8):

I just ran into the same thing.  When installing `rrdtool`, you'll see a suggestion to install `librrds-perl`. Doing that solved my particular need of perl and "use RRDs".

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu 16.04, the RRD::Simple module is in the librrd-simple-perl package, which you can install like this:

```
sudo apt install librrd-simple-perl
```